# Tabs not showing on smaller screens

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am building a React-Bootstrap page and I want a 3 column layout on big screens, but on smaller screens I want to shift it to tabs showing one column at a time based on the selected tab.  On larger screens I indeed get the desired results, but on the smaller screens I can only see my tabs and the content column while the other columns stay hidden.

I have tried several attempts at various className modifiers but none of them seem to work properly.

```js
class HomePage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container id='homepage_container' fluid='true'>
        <ul className='nav nav-tabs d-md-none' role='tablist'>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <a className='nav-link active' href='#controls-col' aria-controls='controls-col' data-toggle='tab' role='tab'>Controls</a>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <a className='nav-link' href='#content-col' aria-controls='content-col' data-toggle='tab' role='tab'>Content</a>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <a className='nav-link' href='#related-content-col' aria-controls='related-content-col' data-toggle='tab' role='tab'>Related</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Row id='homepage_main_row' className='tab-content'>
          <Col id='controls-col' className='homepage_col tab-pane active' role='tabpanel' md={3}>
            <Row float='left'>
              <p>This is the controls</p>
            </Row>
          </Col>
          <Col id='content-col' className='homepage_col tab-pane' role='tabpanel' md={6}>
            <Row className='justify-content-center'>
              <p>This is the Content Panel</p>
            </Row>
          </Col>
          <Col id='related-content-col' className='homepage_col tab-pane' role='tabpanel' md={3}>
            <Row className='float-right'>
              <p>This is the related Content Panel</p>
            </Row>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

And the accompanying scss to modify based on screen size:

```css
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .tab-content > .tab-pane {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

My expected outcome should be that the smaller screens show the tabs as full width elements based on the tab selected.  Yet I still only get the tabs display showing up with the content-col, but cannot switch.  When I click the other tabs I can see the href update in the url bar which indicates they are triggering, but for some reason they are not toggling the 'active' class between the tabs properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you are writing `active` for all `nav-link`,

```
<ul className='nav nav-tabs d-md-none' role='tablist'>
    <li className='nav-item'>
        <a className='nav-link active' href='#controls-col' aria-controls='controls-col' data-toggle='tab' role='tab'>Controls</a>
    </li>
    <li className='nav-item'>
        <a className='nav-link active' href='#content-col' aria-controls='content-col' data-toggle='tab' role='tab'>Content</a>
    </li>
    <li className='nav-item'>
        <a className='nav-link active' href='#related-content-col' aria-controls='related-content-col' data-toggle='tab' role='tab'>Related</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For initial render you must have only 1 `nav-link` as `active`, so remove the `active` from other `nav-link` except first one like,

```
<ul className='nav nav-tabs d-md-none' role='tablist'>
    <li className='nav-item'>
        <a className='nav-link active' href='#controls-col' aria-controls='controls-col' data-toggle='tab' role='tab'>Controls</a>
    </li>
    <li className='nav-item'>
        <a className='nav-link' href='#content-col' aria-controls='content-col' data-toggle='tab' role='tab'>Content</a>
    </li>
    <li className='nav-item'>
        <a className='nav-link' href='#related-content-col' aria-controls='related-content-col' data-toggle='tab' role='tab'>Related</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that.  I have updated by only setting one of the elements to active, but the same behavior persists - updated original question to reflect code changes.

Comment: Have you added `jquery.js`? For me it is working fine.

Comment: I had a sneaking suspicion this could be the case, but I was weighing it against jquery working on the actual DOM vs React's Virtual DOM...

So, with that in mind, what kind of corruptions/issues will I introduce by bringing jquery along for the ride with my React app to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you have added `bootstrap.js` via CDN then you must add `jquery.js` via CDN just for support.